# System.NullReferenceException Error while storing data in Access database

Tags: c#, .net, nullreferenceexception

I am making a simple project where I take "id" and "name" from user and store it into the Access Data base. Whenever I press the Store button System.NullReferenceException Error Comes out. Here is the Code

Where I declared Oledpconnection.

```
public OleDbConnection Con; 
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        string connetionString = null;
        connetionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:/Users/Mujahid/Documents/Visual Studio 2008/Projects/ts/ts/ts.accdb";
        OleDbConnection Con = null;
        Con = new OleDbConnection(connetionString);

        try
        {
            Con.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("Connection Open ! ");
            Con.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ");
        }

    }
```

And here is the insert button programing

```
OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand();
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText="insert into ts(ID,Name)" +"Values ('"+textBox1.Text+"','"+textBox2.Text+"')" ; 
        cmd.Connection= Con;
        Con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        Con.Close();
```

please Help !!

Comment: At what line the exeption happens? Is there some null object in that line?

Comment: If you're using Visual Studio then run the program in Debug mode (F5) and check which line causes the error.

Comment: The code for the insert button seems incomplete. Where do you declare `Con` (It doesn't seem to be a field of the `Form1` class, as it is local in the constructor)? The exception most likely happens in the line `Con.Open`. Make sure that the connection object is valid and properly initialized.

Comment: @0xA3: Above the constructor...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Con needs to be a form scope object, not redeclare in the forms constructor.

```
public OleDbConnection Con;  
public Form1() 
{ 
    InitializeComponent(); 
    string connetionString = null; 
    connetionString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:/Users/Mujahid/Documents/Visual Studio 2008/Projects/ts/ts/ts.accdb"; 

    Con = new OleDbConnection(connetionString); 

    try 
    { 
        Con.Open(); 
        MessageBox.Show("Connection Open ! "); 
        Con.Close(); 

    } 
    catch (Exception) 
    { 
        MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! "); 
    } 

}
```

Comment: Ok Thanks Error Remove but new Error Found 

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll

in the same Line

" Con.Open(); "

Comment: Hmmm, I suspect the name of your database file with spaces in it may need to be delimeted somehow. I'm not sure how access database connection strings work, but you could try this: "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=\"C:/Users/Mujahid/Documents/Visual Studio 2008/Projects/ts/ts/ts.accdb\"";

Answer (score 1):

```
public OleDbConnection Con;
```

...

```
OleDbConnection Con = null;
```

You never initialize the class scoped connection instance.

Comment: I think the OP might need a little more help to understand the difference